# Update access table rst with named cell values from excel

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba, sql

I have got a table in access that I loop through using a DAO recordset. For every recordset I take a bunch of data to an excel spreadsheet and run it through a model in excel. This produces a bunch of results in excel which are calculated in named cells.

I want to be able to update the current recordset in access with these results but am having a tough time doing it.

I have the following code

> code to create a DAO recordset
>
> > code to move to first record
> >
> > > code to parse data to excel
> > >
> > > > code to run a bunch of stuff in excel including a goal seek to calculate results
> > > >
> > > > > next I  use the follwoing code without success

```
            With MyXL

            strSQL = "UPDATE ProductPricing SET Profit = " & .Names("Profit") & ";"

            End With
```

> > > > > Code to move to next record and loop until EOF

Comment: Why are you not executing the sql statement? What exactly is the problem you are having? Any error messages?

Comment: yeah it was stupid me not actually executing the sql! too late late in the night!

Answer (score 0):

Could you not try to keep everything in access and replicate the goal seeking using a user defined function? Failing that I would keep the code in excel and get the code to “pull” the values into excel and then “push” them to access as opposed to pushing the data to excel and pulling it back

Comment: I could do that but I am doing cost modelling for which I like the flexibility that excel offers if it were fed a few constants. I can change the model in excel alot easily compared to access.